# Jacoco missing coverage when test is created

Tags: maven, mockito, junit4, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage

I have a project with spring-boot 2, JUnit 4, jacoco 0.8.6 and I use maven to run unit test, I have the following class:

```java
@Component
public class AccountVOValidator implements FormValidator<AccountVO> {

    @Override
    public void validate(AccountVO object, Object... params) throws GenericException {
            //logic
        }
}
```

This implements `FormValidator` interface, it looks like this:

```java
public interface FormValidator<T> {

    public void validate(T object, Object... params) throws GenericException;

}
```

I already created the test class for that, it looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountVOValidatorTest {

    private TestUtils testUtils = new TestUtils();
    
    @InjectMocks
    private AccountVOValidator accountVOValidator;

        @Test
    public void shouldValidateOk() throws GenericException {
        accountVOValidator.validate(accountVO, transaction);
    }
}
```

I have several unit test for different packages and jacoco report looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSMpX.png)

When I run "mvn clean test", AccountVOValidatorTest ran without problems and all tests passed successfully.
All classes that implements FormValidator interface have a missing coverage in jacoco report, I implements interfaces in my services classes and they got coverage in report, do you have an idea what it happens?

I am not sure why all classes that implements FormValidator interface don't get coverage in jacoco report.

Comment: Do you have tests for each implementation (`FormValidator`)? The given `AccountVOValidatorTest` will only produce a coverage for `AccountVOValidator` but not for any other implementation.

Comment: i have the same issue here, it seems an issue between jacoco and junit